# How to factorise $x^4+x^2+9$

Tags: polynomials

How would you factorize this statement? $x^4 + x^2 + 9$. 
I tried substituting $u$ for $x^2$ but I still have no idea what to do next.

Comment: After subbing for $u = x^2$, you get a quadratic :). So try and solve it!

Comment: Are you studying complex numbers?

Comment: I am not studying complex numbers

Comment: Factorize? Over which field?

Comment: Then I wonder what use the question is to you; are you sure the quartic as posted about is the correct one to factorise?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I feel strongly that the OP has not studied fields..

Comment: I have not studied fields either

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you wish to use only real coefficients.
$$x^4+x^2+9=((x^2+3)^2-6x^2)+x^2$$
$$=(x^2+3)^2-5x^2$$
$$=(x^2+3)^2-(\sqrt 5 x)^2$$
$$=(x^2+3+\sqrt 5 x)(x^2+3-\sqrt 5 x)$$
$$(x^2+\sqrt 5 x +3)(x^2-\sqrt 5 x +3).$$

Comment: This factorization has irrational coefficients: this means that if the OP wants rational coefficients there is no way to factorize it.

Answer (score 0):

> Using the quadratic formula, we get that $x^{2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1^{2}-4*9}}{2} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{35}i}{2}$. This gives that the roots of $x^{4} + x^{2} + 9$ are $\{ \pm \sqrt{\frac{-1 - \sqrt{35}i}{2}} , \pm \sqrt{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{35}i}{2}} \}$ Yielding:

$$
x^{4} + x^{2} + 9 = (x - \sqrt{3} ie^{i \cdot tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2})}) (x + \sqrt{3} ie^{i \cdot tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2})}) (x - \sqrt{3} i e^{i \cdot tan^{-1}(-\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2})}) (x + \sqrt{3} i e^{i \cdot tan^{-1}(-\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2})})
$$

Here $\pm \sqrt{\frac{-1 - \sqrt{35}i}{2}} = \pm \sqrt{3} i e^{i \cdot tan^{-1}(-\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2})}$ and $\pm \sqrt{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{35}i}{2}} = \sqrt{3} ie^{i \cdot tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{35}}{2})}$ giving a factorization over the complex numbers.

Comment: This answer does not help OP at all as @hah has not studied complex numbers.